# python find difference between two list of dictionary

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I try to find out the difference between two list of dictionary based on value of certain keys:

```
test_list1 = [{"name" : "name1", "number": "number1", "data": "data1"}, 
              {"name" : "name2", "number": "number2", "data": "data2"},
              {"name" : "name3", "number": "number3", "data": "data3"},
              {"name" : "name5", "number": "number5", "data": "data5"}]

test_list2 = [{"name" : "name1", "number": "number1", "data": "data5"},
              {"name" : "name2", "number": "number2", "data": "data2"},
              {"name" : "name3", "number": "number3", "data": "data3"},
              {"name" : "name4", "number": "number4", "data": "data4"}]
```

I try to find out dict with "number" in test_list1 but not in test_list2, for example,
`{"name" : "name5", "number": "number5", "data": "data5"}`
is in test_list1 but not in test_list2:

```
res2 = [i for i in test_list1 for j in test_list2 if i.get("number") != j.get("number")]
```

the result is:

```
[{'name': 'name1', 'number': 'number1', 'data': 'data1'}, {'name': 'name1', 'number': 'number1', 'data': 'data1'}, {'name': 'name1', 'number': 'number1', 'data': 'data1'}, {'name': 'name2', 'number': 'number2', 'data': 'data2'}, {'name': 'name2', 'number': 'number2', 'data': 'data2'}, {'name': 'name2', 'number': 'number2', 'data': 'data2'}, {'name': 'name3', 'number': 'number3', 'data': 'data3'}, {'name': 'name3', 'number': 'number3', 'data': 'data3'}, {'name': 'name3', 'number': 'number3', 'data': 'data3'}, {'name': 'name5', 'number': 'number5', 'data': 'data5'}, {'name': 'name5', 'number': 'number5', 'data': 'data5'}, {'name': 'name5', 'number': 'number5', 'data': 'data5'}, {'name': 'name5', 'number': 'number5', 'data': 'data5'}]
```

how to get the dict with "number" in test_list1 but not in test_list2 as following:

```
{"name" : "name5", "number": "number5", "data": "data5"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```py
difference = filter((lambda x: x["number"] not in { y["number"] for y in test_list2}), test_list1)
difference = list(difference)
>>>[{'name': 'name5', 'number': 'number5', 'data': 'data5'}]
```

This will give you a list of course, I don't know if there is only one difference between two lists, but if you think there can only be one difference you can access the dictionary via difference[0]

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to use set operations here.

- Declare a set of `number` values of `test_list2`.
- Filter entries where `number` value doesn't belong to the set with list comprehension.

```py
test_list2_numbers = {entry.get('number') for entry in test_list2}              
res2 = [i for i in test_list1 if i.get('number') not in test_list2_numbers]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def find(left, right, key): 
    map_ = {
        i[key]: i
        for i in right
    }

    for j in left:
        if map_.get(j[key]) is None:
            yield j


test_left = [
    {"name" : "name1", "number": "number1", "data": "data1"}, 
    {"name" : "name2", "number": "number2", "data": "data2"},
    {"name" : "name3", "number": "number3", "data": "data3"},
    {"name" : "name5", "number": "number5", "data": "data5"},
]

test_right = [
    {"name" : "name1", "number": "number1", "data": "data5"},
    {"name" : "name2", "number": "number2", "data": "data2"},
    {"name" : "name3", "number": "number3", "data": "data3"},
    {"name" : "name4", "number": "number4", "data": "data4"},
]

expected = [{"name" : "name5", "number": "number5", "data": "data5"}]

assert list(find(test_left, test_right, "number")) == expected
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).